# Grunt run task with override config

Tags: gruntjs

I always used gulp for all my tasks automation, but in our current project we use grunt and I can't figure out how to make very simple thing:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
        scripts: {
            files: '**/*.js',
            tasks: ['karma:watch:run'],
        }
    },
    myWatch: {
        scripts: {
            files: '**/*.js',
            tasks: ['do_my_own_task_but_not_karma'],
        }
    }
});

//current task
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

//doesn't work
grunt.registerTask('myWatchTask', ['myWatch']);
```

Basically I just want to override current watch config for my own custom task, because I don't want karma to run tests each time I change js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an new configuration within the `watch` configuration object:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    main: {
      scripts: {
          files: '**/*.js',
          tasks: ['karma:watch:run'],
      }
    },
    myWatch: {
      scripts: {
          files: '**/*.js',
          tasks: ['do_my_own_task_but_not_karma'],
      }
  }
},
});
```

Then you can run `grunt watch:main` or `grunt watch:myWatch`, [see these docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets).

If you want to have something that is watched always you can add it to the root of the `watch` configuration object.

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    files: '**/always.js',
    tasks: ['always'],
    main: {
      scripts: {
          files: '**/*.js',
          tasks: ['karma:watch:run'],
      }
    },
    myWatch: {
      scripts: {
          files: '**/*.js',
          tasks: ['do_my_own_task_but_not_karma'],
      }
  }
},
});
```

now `grunt watch:myWatch` will run it's dedicated config and the config in the root of the `watch` configuration object.